# Android api level 25.0 NuGet causes trouble in visual studio 2015 and Xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015. 
My project is on Team Foundation Server, I updated Android API level 25.0 NuGet for using Google Firebase messaging.

Now when I load the project in Visual Studio 2015 and change debug to release mode, Visual Studio freezes and hangs.

When I remove API level and Firebase messaging DLL then it works smoothly. What should I do?

Comment: Did you find any solution

Comment: yeah actually after updation xamarion on my visual studio some files got corrupt in my local system. i again install  xamarin and its work properly.